# Audio Recording in Background throws IllegalStateException when I try to stop it

Tags: android, audiorecord

I am creating a background audio recorder using `Service` class. When I start recording it works fine but when I stop it, it throws `IllegalStateException` on `onStop()`.

Here is my Service Class Code:

```
public class AudioRecorderService extends Service {

    MediaRecorder mAudioRecorder;
    String fileName = null;

    public AudioRecorderService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       setupRecorder();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void setupRecorder(){

        fileName = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "test.mp4";

        mAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(256);
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);

        try {
            mAudioRecorder.prepare();
            mAudioRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (mAudioRecorder != null) {
            mAudioRecorder.stop();
            mAudioRecorder.reset();
            mAudioRecorder.release();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

I am unable to figure out what's wrong with the code. Please can anyone help????

Comment: Your code seems fine, can you post logcat?

Comment: Now my app is getting ANR again and again as I try to execute the AudioRecorder Service class. I guess there is some threading issue.

Answer (score 0):

While starting and stopping it should be in this order. Incase of any errors notification is necessary

```
MediaRecorder recorder = null;

private void startRecording(File file) {
   if (recorder != null) {
      recorder.release();
   }
   recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   recorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
   recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
   try {
      recorder.prepare();
      recorder.start();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("Error", "io problems while preparing [" +
            file.getAbsolutePath() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Now `java.lang.IllegalStateException`
Happens when you do not follow the order above, miss some important steps or when `prepare()` failed, but you continue anyway. The latter is where it is most likely to go wrong. You should only call `start()` when `prepare()` did exit without exceptions. Otherwise you will get an `IllegalStateException`. Since it is a `RuntimeException` you might not catch it and your app will force close.

While stopping follow this order

```
private void stopRecording() {
   if (recorder != null) {
      recorder.stop();
      recorder.release();
      recorder = null;
   }
}
```

and last but not the lease in Manifest , the permission

```
<uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of  `mAudioRecorder.reset();`

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (mAudioRecorder != null) {
            mAudioRecorder.stop();
            // here is error
            mAudioRecorder.reset();
            mAudioRecorder.release();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Update it.:**

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (mAudioRecorder != null) {
            mAudioRecorder.stop();
            mAudioRecorder.release();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Refer official site : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: How can you say `mAudioRecorder.reset();` is reason for error?

Answer (score 0):

I have added these 2 permissions on AndroidManifest.xml and it won't crash anymore.
P/S: The App will ask for your permission for recording the audio when upon starting it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```